# como filtrar datos con json y php

Tags: php, mysql, swift, post

Necesito si alguien que me ayude, tengo una estructura que recibe datos de una base de datos mysql, quisiera mostrar los datos en la app pero filtrando los datos que coincidan con una variable que defino al cargar la app, tengo la siguiente estructura:

```
func datos3(){

        let url = URL(string: "http://test/test.php")

        Alamofire.request(url!).responseJSON { (response) in

            let result = response.data
            do {
                self.filtro = try JSONDecoder().decode([ClientDADES].self, from: result!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tabla.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error al conectar php", error)
            }
        }

    }
```

y en php:

```
<?php

    $servername = "test";
    $database = "test";
    $username = "test";
    $password = "test";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    $conn-> set_charset('utf-8');


        $resultado = array();
        $temporal= array();

        $conn->query("SET NAMES UTF8");

    $sel = $conn ->query("SELECT * FROM `Cli`");

    while ($f = $sel->fetch_assoc()) {
       $temporal = $f;

       // $temporal = $f;
        array_push($resultado, $temporal);
    }

    echo json_encode($resultado);

    $sel->close();
    $conn->close();

    ?>
```

Comment: Hola hace un foreach al en el que tenes los datos, le pones un if dentro que compare los datos, los que coincidan con lo que buscas lo vas agregando a un array nuevo, al finalizar el for tendras un array con los datos filtrados.

Comment: si, pero los datos los debo filtrar en la app y no se que código debo utilizar

Comment: Si si, eso mismo que te dije intenta hacerlo en la app luego edita tu pregunta con lo que intentaste hacer si es que no te funciono y asi podemos seguir ayudandote.

Comment: Erick, lo siento es que soy nuevo en esto y no entiendo lo que quieres decir, estoy buscando un ejemplo para filtrar el json que devuelve la consulta